# Mailchimp API error in Magento1.9

Tags: email, magento-1.9, mailchimp

I Install the Mailchimp extension in magento1.9 and Directly I added the API key in the **system->configuration->mailchimp** and Iam getting Following Error.

> for Api Call: API call to lists?fields=lists&count=100 failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) -

**SSL version-3** 
**Mailchimp version - 1.5.1.**

Operating System: **CentOs**

Can anyone please help..

Comment: try this link: https://yikesplugins.com/support/knowledge-base/i-receive-the-error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-why/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Download cacert.pem file from here:
   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. eg: Save the file in /etc/pki/tls.
3. Open your php.ini file and add this line:

   ```
   curl.cainfo="/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem"
   ```
4. Restart/Reload your Apache server (`service httpd reload`)